# Is it possible to wrap a Web Form Control with an MVC 3 HTML Helper?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controls

We have an ASP.Net ScriptControl that is shared between web app projects. One project is being converted to MVC 3 and the shared control needs to be used but of course MVC doesn't have controls or view state.

My ideal solution would be to wrap the control in a html helper so it can be placed on the view. Then, I can send/receive data to/from the control inside the helper.

Is it possible AND is it decently trivial to do so?

Comment: I am trying to do something similar, specifically, I would like to utilize a RadComboBox containing a RadTreeView in a Razor view. Any help would be appreciated. I have previously wrapped the ReCaptcha control into an HtmlHelper, so I know how the basics work, but I am having trouble with this one because it seems to require a Page to be set for the control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as it doesn't rely on ViewState or Postback, yes, you usually can.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't do a lot of web development so I'm trying to figure out the basics of how it would be wrapped and basic code structure to wrap the control. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

To be safe in this scenario I would include an ASPX page in your solution rather than attempting to hack it to work. It 'can' work - at times but behavior can be buggy depending what it is looking for behind the scenes so it can be a hack.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work because I don't think that I can simply add a webform in an MVC project. Additionally the control is a ScriptControl so it requires a ScriptManager and so of course it won't work because of that as well.